# Generate texture map

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to create a 3D first-person game which could run in browser using webGL technology. I have generated a landscape with Blender and now I'm bothering with textures. In my game I scale Blender's landscape in 1500 times to achieve large world but with this approach I can't use single texture file for all this world. So i was drop into technique called texture splatting. As result I wrote a shader that combine 4 textures in one using texture map file which look similar to this:

[image]

4 RGBA channels in this image set's the intensity of 4 textures. Here is how it works - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMaaumAB_Rg&feature=youtu.be

Now I want to find a way to genereate that texture map. I would like to be able to draw in in blender on landscape mesh. I was following steps in this video https://vimeo.com/15679785 but having problems with it a here is where I need help.

I'm adding dirt texture as basic texture, then I'm adding new texture of type `image or movie` but I select `new` to create new image. I deselect `influence->diffuse->color` and check `influence->stencil` and `influence->rgb to intensity` for this texture. Then I'm adding grass texture and expecting then drawing on landscape mesh in `texture paint` mode  will 
reflect in changes in texture map layer and will bring a grass on mesh. But when I drawing it only change dirt texture and has no any effect on texture which is supposed to be texture map. What am I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Here are screenshots of texture settings I'm using:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZdeV.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2vnr.png

Comment: I can see on your screenshot that you have been painting the stencil on your dirt texture

Comment: That was a question about. I didn't know how to switch drawing slot to paint on stencil texture instead of painting on dirt texture.